# Find substring that would fit inside UILabel of certain area

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

For a UILabel of certain width, with certain font and font size, i want to calculate amount of characters that would make 7 lines worth of text inside it + ... (three dots showing continuation). Is there a fancier way to achieve this? Currently what i'm trying is counting up to X amount of characters or 7 new line characters, which ever comes first and i cut on the text right there.

More Detail:
Trying to make an expandable row Cell which contains the UILabel, i'm achieving this with auto layout... So to control the cell expansion, i change the text to be full text or a substring of that, with a button below which toggles between the string vs substring. All of that is working. The problem i'm getting is my method of finding the substring isnt very neat. Its not consistent on how it handles text of different combination of characters or newlines. I get variations of how it looks and sometimes it just ends with three dots on a new line rather than finishing on the 7th line.

Comment: What about using the lines property of UILabel? Set it to 7 and you'll get 7 or less rows.

Comment: Hmmm, will restricting lines automatically work instead of changing text? leme give it a quick try...

Comment: It worked :D, i was so vision tunnelled on making it work with auto layout before that i had kept in mind that putting lines to 0 is only going to work for that... Thanks @D.Mika

Comment: Perfect. I added an answer so you can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even using auto layout you can still use the `lines` property of `UILabel` to limit the number of lines displayed by the label.

So set it 7 and you'll get 7 or less rows. Just assign the complete text.